# Why does View.getShowingView() dont return the currentView?

Tags: mobile, view, dojo

after launching my app there is a command:

```
var currentView = dojox.mobile.View.getShowingView();
```

i "required" dojox.mobile.View but currentView never shows the currentView, it stops at the above command. I am using dojo 1.8.3. What's wrong or how can i get my current view?

greets Tom

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a reference to a view in your page and call the method on that view.

For Example:
I know one of my views id is "mainView".

```
    registry.byId("mainView").getShowingView().performTransition("mainView", -1, "slide");
```

registry.byId will search for the mainview.
On that view you can do .getShowingView().
This searches the sibling views for the currently visible view.

And for example on that view you can add a transition to the mainView, like a 'return to home' function.

Comment: But if your showingView and transitionView is the same, something strange happens ;D